# How can I show the console of my console application in this scenario?

Tags: c#, console-application

When you launch a console application by double-clicking it in explorer, the console is visible. However, if you run a console application through an already non-visible application, the console is invisible (maybe because it is trying to read the standard output or something).

So, how can I show my console window to the user even if the console application was started by a background app?

I already tried the `ShowWindow` and `SetForeground` Windows API without any luck. I also tried the following.

```
//paths for starting the server.
var processInformation = new ProcessStartInfo(myOwnPath);
processInformation.WorkingDirectory = myOwnWorkingDirectory;
processInformation.UseShellExecute = false;
processInformation.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
processInformation.CreateNoWindow = false;

processInformation.RedirectStandardInput = false;
processInformation.RedirectStandardError = false;
processInformation.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

Process.Start(processInformation);
```

Any ideas?

**Note:** It is perfectly fine if the application needs to launch itself and shut down the old instance to get the console window visible.

Comment: You can't shove a window into the user's face.

Comment: The user in this scenario is only myself. The problem is that a build server executes the recently executed program, from where it deploys itself to a new location and runs itself from there. But since the console window contains important data, I need it to be visible.

Comment: Who ever looks at a build server?  Redirect the output of the program and email it to somebody.  Something like that.

Comment: The build server is also my production environment. It **is** the final server that the program will run on.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `UseShellExecute` to true.  Setting it to false lets you to redirect input, output, and error streams.